# Vue Router code firing before app creation finished?

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

Whenever I try to load / refresh my app via a deeplink the router code fires first. And fails because the authetication token has not been set yet... I assume that the `beforeCreate` of the app should be the first thing to be executed.

The browser console displays:

`router beforeEnter`

`app beforeCreate`

Router code:

```
...
const router = new VueRouter({
    routes: [{
      path: '/article/:articleId',
      name: 'article',
      component: Article,
      beforeEnter (to, from, next) {
        console.log('router beforeEnter')
        // Load stuff from backend with axios
      }
    }]
}
```

Application startup code

```
...
Vue.use(VueRouter)

import router from './router'

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  store: store,
  router: router,
  beforeCreate: function() {
    console.log('app beforeCreate')
    // get authentication token from localStorage and put in axios header
  },
  render: h => h(App),
})
```

What am I missing here? How can I make sure the app creation code is executed first?

Comment: I assume the auth token is in localstorage or something similar? Or do you have to request it async?

Comment: Yes it is in localstorage, nothing async there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the behaviour is intended and correct.
Before something get's rendered the router decides what to render.

But how to solve your problem?

First i have a persistent auth module like this:

```
export default {
  name: 'auth',
  namespaced: false,
  state: {
    token: undefined,
    payload: undefined
  },

  mutations: {
    clearAuth (state) {
      state.token = undefined
      state.payload = undefined
    },

    setToken (state, token) {
      let payload
      try {
        payload = JSON.parse(atob(token.split('.')[1]))
      } catch (e) {
        payload = undefined
        token = undefined
      }
      state.token = token
      state.payload = payload
    }
  },

  getters: {
    token: state => state.token,
    isAuthenticated: state => !!state.token,
    hasRenewToken: state => !!state.payload && state.payload.renewable
  }
}
```

Then i use vuex-persistedstate to initialise the vuex module.

```
import createPersistedState from 'vuex-persistedstate'

const store = new Vuex.Store({
  modules: {
    auth,
    ... // other modules
  },
  plugins: [
    createPersistedState({
      paths: ['auth']
    })
  ]
})
```

Now whenever the store is created all auth informations are in the store.

And at the end i use a little wrapper for axios like this (request.js):

```
import axios from 'axios'
import store from '@/store'

const requestHandler = config => {
  config.headers = {
    'Authorization': store.getters.token
  }
  config.crossDomain = true
  config.method = 'POST'
  return config
}

const request = axios.create()
request.interceptors.request.use(requestHandler)

export default request
```

Now i do not import axios but request.js whereever i want to make a request.

I hope this approach helps you. At least it works for me

Comment: "the behaviour is intended and correct" - you are absolutely right. I am going to use your interceptor idea, that fixes things for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried loading it before the router? AFAIK the Vue object loads everything synchronous.

```
 new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  store: store,
  beforeCreate: function() {
    console.log('app beforeCreate')
    // set authentication token in axios header
  },
  router: router,
  render: h => h(App),
 })
```

Comment: Yes I did. That does not make a difference is this case because in effect a bunch of options are passed into the Vue constructor. And Vue takes it from there.